# Generate Statistics from check-out GDB While performing Check-in

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase, replication

I have created Check-out Replica from the main ArcSDE GDB. I have below questions.

How to generate statistics of the edits performed on the check-out GDB, before check-in. for example: i want to have a report on edits as compared to the parent version and location of edits, type of editd (Attribute, Spatial).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to enable editor tracking. You would be able to see what was edited, who edited it, what day and time it was edited. Editor tracking creates four new columns, however.

The other way would be to write a database trigger to populate a column or table any time a insert or update is made on the feature class. You could populate the desired column with the date and time the edit was made.

Editor Tracking
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000016p000000

SQL Server Trigger
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Oracle Trigger
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm

Hope that helps!